# how to get google maps api v3 to show point?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am using [Google Maps Api v3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/) to display a map.

This is the JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myOptions = {
         zoom: 8,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng($("#lat").val(), $("#long").val()),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID  
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
```

But the map doesn't highlight the point. It just shows the area on the map...what I would like it to look like is this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the source code of this example with a marker: 
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple.html

Example using your code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng($("#lat").val(), $("#long").val());
            //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

            var contentString = '<div id="content">Info window html</div>';

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Marker Title'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code below your code

```
var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng($("#lat").val(), $("#long").val())
, Marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: LatLng, map: map });
```